# Вывод данных из файлов с разными именами C++

Tags: c++

Имеется совокупность файлов с некоторыми данными, как осуществить открытие данных файлов в цикле, с выводом на экран необходимых значений, если имена у файлов разные?

*Cs_A%2.2d_F00.Out*, *Cs_A%2.2d_R00.Out*, *Cs_C%2.2d_F00.Out* и *Cs_C%2.2d_R00.Out*, i-изменяется от 0 до 25. В примере рассматривается только случай для имен Cs_A(00-25)_R00.Out, как сделать для остальных?

```
sprintf(name[i], "Cs_A%2.2d_F00.Out", i);

if (name[i]==0){   
    cout<<"Error open %s" << name[i]<< endl;   
    return 1;    
}
```

Comment: Как вариант можешь использовать контейнеры, а после по ним проходить в цикле

Comment: @Defiler  Вы знаете человеческий язык? Вы а состоянии на человеческом языке описать задачу, чтобы было понятно читающим?! Что это за имя файла Cs_A%2.2d_F00.Out, и как получилось Cs_A(00-25)_R00.Out,?

Comment: Имена формируются по какому-то правилу? или это просто 4 заранее известных имени?

Answer (score 1):

Если с числами вопросов не возникает о использовании цикла, то для строковых составляющих можно использовать массив. Например:

```
#include <iostream>

const char* names[] = { "one", "two", "three" };

int main() {

    for( unsigned i=0; i<sizeof(names)/sizeof(*names); ++i ) {
        std::cout << names[i] << '\n';
    }
}
```

Надеюсь, этого достаточно для понимания идеи.

Comment: Только надо поосторожнее быть с конструкцией вида `sizeof(names)/sizeof(*names)`, а то можно получить не те результаты, которые ожидаешь. Лучше все-таки хранить длину массива или использовать `std::vector`, `std::array` и т.п.

Comment: @PavelParshin (disclaimer) код только для демонстрации. Понятно, что если пытаться использовать эту конструкцию где-то в функции, принимающей массив (а по сути указатель на начало), работать оно не будет. `std::vector` тут явный оверхед, т.к. изменение контейнера не требуется. `std::array` будет более приемлемым в промышленном коде.